# asp vb gridview changes the input value by it self

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, webforms

I'm using **asp.net web form gridview** and I run into a problem when inserting a new record from footer.

my footer has the different input that should be submitted but when I submit the record they change.

for example, I have an input fname if I type the name "*Issa*" I get it like this "*,Issa*"

**the "," character is being added and I don't know why**

this is how I retrieve the record.

```
Dim fname As String = TryCast(staffs_gridvw.FooterRow.FindControl("footer_sfname_txtbox"), TextBox).Text.Trim
```

and this is how my templet field looks like.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="First Name">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("sfname") %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="sfname_txtbox" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("sfname") %>'></asp:TextBox>
    </EditItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="footer_sfname_txtbox" CssClass="form-control" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

any suggestion on how can I fix this issue???

Comment: Have you tried having a look at the post request from the client side to see if the extra characters are already there ?

Comment: How can I do that!

Comment: in Chrome or Edge, hit F12 to bring up the developer tools, and then click on Network tab to monitor requests sent from the client. From there you can find what is the payload of your particular POST request, and in particular the values send.

Comment: I looked around the network section in the console. nothing seems to help me

Answer (score 0):

Hum, I am un-able to re-produce this error.

My markup:

```
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ShowFooter="true">
            <Columns>
      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="First Name">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("FirstName") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="sfname_txtbox" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("FirstName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="footer_sfname_txtbox" CssClass="form-control" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>

        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
```

My code to fill:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then
        LoadGrid
    End If
End Sub


Sub LoadGrid()
    Dim rstData As DataTable
    rstData = MyRst("SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA ORDER BY HotelName")
    GridView1.DataSource = rstData
    GridView1.DataBind()

End Sub
```

We now get this:

[image]

So I type in hello world into that text box, hit the button, with this code:

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim fname As String = TryCast(GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("footer_sfname_txtbox"), TextBox).Text.Trim

    Debug.Print(fname)

End Sub
```

And I see this:

[image]

So, I guess the question is what other operations are you doing to that GV?

## Edit: Button is also in the the GV footer

Ok, so then we have this:

```
    <div style="padding:25px;width:20%">
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ShowFooter="true" CssClass="table">
            <Columns>
      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="First Name">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("FirstName") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="sfname_txtbox" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("FirstName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="footer_sfname_txtbox" CssClass="form-control" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Hotel">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblHotel" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("HotelName") %>' ></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button" />
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>

    </div>
```

And code to load - same as before.

So, now we see this:

[image]

Of course, the button is now in the GV - so I can't double click to wire up a event, but you of course then use markup.

Type in onclick= (hit ctrl-space bar under the quotes) - and then you get this option:

[image]

Ok, so now we have our event behind.

This code:

```
Protected Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim fname As String = TryCast(GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("footer_sfname_txtbox"), TextBox).Text.Trim
    Debug.Print(fname)

End Sub
```

And now this:

[image]

And click on button, I see/get this:

[image]

Comment: but for me, I'm submitting the data from a button inside the footer of the gidview

Comment: Well, that is a big huge mount Everest of a detail, right? But, it should not matter. See my above edit - I moved the button to the footer - no change in the results. So, at this point, I can't reproduce your issue.